# Manipulate on Mathematica Online

Tags: mathematica-online

I am absolutely new to Mathematica Online. Using Mathematica 10.1.0.0 on my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.10.3), the following code works perfectly.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Blue,
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, arrowA}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, arrowB}]
   },
  PlotRange -> 5,
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
  PlotLabel -> 
   Row[{"\[Theta] = ", 
     NumberForm[angleBetweenVectors[arrowA, arrowB], {3, 1}], 
     "\[Degree]"}]
  ],
 {{arrowA, {3, 3}}, Locator},
 {{arrowB, {-3, 3}}, Locator},
 Initialization :> (
   angleBetweenVectors[u_, v_] := 
    ArcCos[(u.v)/(Norm[u] Norm[v])]/Degree // N
   )
 ]
```

However, when I enter it on Mathematica Online, I get the following result.

[image]

Does this mean that Manipulate is limited when used on Mathematica Online? If so, is there documentation that says what will work and what will not?

Comment: I have not tried Manipulate in the cloud for sometime, since when I tried it initially, many `Dynamics` did not work. Here is a link that lists something that did not work then [Cloud Dynamic support](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/283411)

Comment: I'm no longer unofficially authorative on this subject, but Locator is not Cloud Notebook/CDF compatable and shouldn't be expected to be so for some while. Currently Dynamic output is actually static server side generated output, see how Manipulate[Plot[x^n,{x,1,10}],{n,1,10}] behaves in the cloud.